# ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR when returning file from ASP.NET action

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have some old Web API action method which returns CSV file. It worked for long time, but recently stopped. Now it causes ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR in Chrome is often associated with Avast security as described [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sfAqeo4hDy8). In my case however it's not caused by Avast, and other web browsers throw exceptions too.

My action method looks as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("csv")]
public HttpResponseMessage SomeMethod([FromUri]SomeSearchCriteria sc)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string content = someLogic.SomeSearchmethod(sc);
        writer.Write(content);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "Export.csv" };
        return result;
    }              
}
```

The method is called by angular front end by simple change of `window.location` on button click.

Whole action method is executed properly, with no exceptions. Error is shown only by web browser.

Flushing sockets in Chrome as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867014/what-mean-err-spdy-protocol-error-in-nginx) does not solve the issue.

Comment: In what browsers (and what are versions of those browsers) you experience this error?

Comment: This specific error in (as far as I remember newest) Chrome, but in IE, and Firefox there are errors too, however there's no error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried this method in API controller and call through chrome browser, it throws `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

There is some issue in response filled with `StreamContent`, use  `ByteArrayContent` in result content, it works perfectly.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("csv")]
    public HttpResponseMessage SomeMethod([FromUri]SomeSearchCriteria sc)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string content = "test";
            writer.Write(content);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            //result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray());
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "Export.csv" };
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :).

Comment: But _why_?  Should an issue be filed with ASPNet?