# Cascading Dropdown Error ASP.Net Core 2.0

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a cascading dropdown for City based on the Province using `jQuery` but I keep receiving the error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR

My Javascript is firing.

```
$(function () {
    $('#provinceList').change(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Cities/GetCityByProvince";
        var ddlSource = "#provinceList";
        $.getJSON(url, { provID: $(ddlSource).val() }, function () {
            $("#cityList").append("<option value=1> Hi + </option>")
            // });
            //$("#cityList").html(items);
        })
    });
});
```

And the return object from my class is populated correctly

```
public ActionResult GetCityByProvince(int provID)
{
    List<City> cities = new List<City>();
    cities = _context.Cities.Where(m => m.ProvinceId == provID).ToList();
    cities.Insert(0, new City { ID = 0, CityName = "Please select your nearest city" });
    var x = Json(new SelectList(cities, "Id", "CityName"));
    return Json(x);
}
```

However I am still getting this error.

Comment: May help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952906/err-spdy-protocol-error-when-returning-file-from-asp-net-action

Comment: @FelipeOriani I can't really see how the link you posted is relevant to the question.

Comment: Can you try a different browser? Also take a look at the network tab of the browser’s developer tools, to see if the request is done properly. Also try to reproduce the request separately, outside of your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution.
And try another browser.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
            $('select').on('change', function () {
                if ($(this).attr('data-parent') != null) {
                    var parent = $(this).attr('data-parent').replace(".", "\\\\.");
                    if (parent != null && param != undefined) {
                        var data = $.extend(
                        {
                            render: $(this).attr('data-parent'),
                            url: $(parent).attr('data-url'),
                            type: "get",
                            dataType: "html",
                            data:
                                    {
                                        "value": ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('data-master') ? null : $(this).val())
                                    }
                        }, data);
                        FromJson(data);
                        if ($(this).val() != "-Select-") {
                            $(parent).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $(parent).hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });


function FromJson(param) {

    $.ajax({
        url: param.url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: param.data,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            var options = $(param.render);
            $(param.render).empty();
            options.append($('<option value=""/>').text("-Select-"));
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $.each(data, function () {
                    if (param.dataText == null) {
                        options.append($('<option />').val(this.Value).text(this.Text));
                    }
                    else {
                        options.append($('<option />').val(this.Value).text(this.str));
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                options.append($('<option />').text("-Error-"));
            }

            if (param.selected != null && param.selected != 0) {
                $(param.render).val(param.selected);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then;

```
<select data-parent="#state" id="city" name="city" class="form-control valid" data-url="/Json/city" data-type="live">
</select>

<select data-parent="#town" id="state" name="state" class="form-control valid"  data-url="/Json/state">
</select>

<select data-parent="#zip" id="town" name="town" class="form-control valid"  data-url="/Json/town">
</select>

<select id="zip" name="zip" class="form-control valid"  data-url="/Json/zip">
</select>
```