# Limit on number of cookies allowed? - err_spdy_protocol_error

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies, session-cookies

On Chrome and  Firefox I sometimes get the following error **err_spdy_protocol_error**
 once I call the following website [https://checkideas.com/.](https://checkideas.com/)

I have researched on this topic on the internet and on this platform as well. I also found a working solution. Once I delete all the cookies and reload the webpage the error does not emerge.

So if you click on the website for the 1st time it will definitely work. But once there are number of cookies given the website cannot always be called. This is only the pattern I have identified so far. However I would like to have a sustainable solution.

What do I have to do to avoid this issue so that this issue does not occur? What is the source of the error?

Unfortunately following responses on similar questions did not answer my question:

[Console errors. Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083453/console-errors-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response)

[What mean ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867014/what-mean-err-spdy-protocol-error-in-nginx)

I also cannot identify any issue with the certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is related to the SPDY Protocol or an antivirus setting.

Updating to a later version of the browser should help fix the error (Google Chrome and Mozilla have dropped support for the SPDY Protocol.

This article contains methods that should help you fix the [ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR](https://www.gadgetdetected.com/2017/05/how-to-fix-err_spdy_protocol_error/)

on Google Chrome or Mozilla.