# I get “Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error” in Angular 7 using DotNet Core web Api

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, angular7

> I am trying to retrieve data in Angular 7 using Dotnet Core Web Api, I
>   am getting data when i browse localhost url of Api in Google Chrome as
>   shown in image.

[image]

> When i test Api in postman i am getting this response as shown in
>   image.

[image]

> On UI side i am getting this error in console as shown in image.

[image]

> **Here Is my service Method for getting data**

```
  GetJobTitle(): Observable<any> {
    debugger;
    return this.http.get(this._baseUrl)
      .pipe(
        map((response: Response) => {
          return response;
        }),
        catchError((error: Response) => {
          return throwError(console.log(error));
        })
      );
  }
```

> **And here is component.ts Get Method**

```
  GetAllJobTitle(): void {
    debugger;
    this.jobTitleService.GetJobTitle()
      .subscribe(
        (data: JobTitleModel[]) => {
          this.MyDataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
          this.MyDataSource.data = data;
          console.log("Data retrieved !!!" + data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log('There was an error while retrieving Positions !!!' + error);
        });
  }
```

I googled it but couldn't find any solution.
I have also added CORS in Api. Can anyone suggest me what am i missing here or what i did wrong here?

Comment: you may be doing nothing wrong SPDY_ERROR is caused by different reasons beyond your front end code control check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867014/what-does-err-spdy-protocol-error-mean-in-nginx

Comment: Thanks @arpitsharma for reply,
but i am unable to understand the answers provided in that link as i am new to Angular and don't have any Deployment Experience.
Rightnow whatever i am developing is in my local machine and not on live server, hope you are getting my point.
If you have any other suggestion please share with me.

Comment: test on IE or Firefox or safari

Comment: @arpitsharma Problem is still same, even when i test on FireFox , IE and Edge.